# Full width section titles in scrartcl with parskip option

Tags: sectioning, parskip, scrartcl

The subsection title in the following document should fit in a single line. The last word slips into the second line, although there is still enough space in the first.

```
\documentclass[parskip = half+]{scrartcl} 

\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{This subsection title should fit in a single line but it doesn't}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

If I waive the `parskip = half+` option the title is in a single line but I need that option for other purposes.

**Update**

I need the `sectsty` package to change the part format. The `parbox` workaround causes the page number in the table of contents to be too far to the right.

```
\documentclass[parskip = half+]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\partfont{\centering\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addpart{Part}
    \section{This section title should fit in a single line but it doesn't}
    \lipsum[10]
    \section{\parbox{\linewidth}{This section title should fit in a single line but it doesn't}} 
    \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get rid of `secsty` and configure the part format using `setkomafont` instead:

```
\documentclass[parskip = half+]{scrartcl} 
\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\raggedpart}{\centering}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \addpart{Part}
    \section{This section title should fit in a single line and now it does}
    \lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: apply esdds hint.

Comment: `\centering` is not a font command. Use `\renewcommand{\raggedpart}{\centering}` to center the part heading and `\setkomafont{part}{\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont}` for the part font.